# HTML5. Как передать массив строк в функцию javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Ввожу информацию через поле ввода, которое нужно передать в функцию js в качестве массива строк. Однако получается только отправить строку. Пробовал ее преобразовать в массив, но не выходит. Как мне сразу отправить в функцию массив строк?

```html
<section>
<html>
<head>    <meta charset="windows-1251" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Введите строки</p>
     <form method="get">
        <input type="text" name="string" id="text_string" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="send" value="Отправить" onclick=GetString(text_string.value) />

        <script language="JavaScript">
            function GetString(massiv) {
                let num = 0;
                let tp;
                for (let i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
                    if (massiv[i] == " ") {
                        num++;
                    }
                }
                let massiv_string = new Array(num + 1);
                let tmp;
                for (let i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
                    if (massiv[i] != " ") {
                        tmp += massiv[i];
                    } else {
                        massiv_string.push(tmp);
                        tmp = "";
                    }
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < massiv_string.length; i++) {
                    getMessage(massiv_string[i]);
                }
            }
            function getMessage(word) {
                alert(word);
            }
        </script>

    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
let massiv_string = new Array(num + 1);
...
massiv_string.push(tmp);
```

Создается массив длины `num + 1` с пустыми элементами. `push` продолжает сверху добавлять элементы, но индексы от `0` до `num + 1` неизменно остаются пустыми.

К тому же, в JS для создания массива не нужно заранее знать его размер: предварительный подсчет пробелов лишний.

Исправленный вариант:

```js
function getString(str) {
  let arr = [""]; // Создается массив с одним элементом - пустой строкой
  let index = 0; // Указывает на номер элемента в массиве, с которым сейчас работаем
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == " ") {
      arr[++index] = ""; // Увеличивает index,
      // заодно под этим номером создает пустую строку в массиве.
      continue;
    }
    
    arr[index] += str[i];
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // ненужный перебор, можно было вызывать в предыдущем цикле. Но пусть будет
    getMessage(arr[i]);
  }
}

function getMessage(word) {
  console.log(word);
}
```

```html
<form method="get">
  <input id="text_string" value="test1 test2 test3">
  <input type="button" value="Отправить" onclick="getString(text_string.value)">
</form>
```

И более "правильный" вариант :D

```js
let text = document.querySelector("#text");
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  text.value.split(" ").forEach(log);
  // split разбивает строку в массив, по переданному разделителю.

  // forEach - встроенный метод перебора массива.
  // Берет функцию и вызывает её для каждого элемента. А как первый параметр
  // функции (оно же word) == передается очередной элемент массива.
});

function log(word) {
  console.log(word);
}
```

```html
<form method="get">
  <input id="text" value="test1 test2 test3">
  <input id="btn" type="button" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Формально, через `onclick` можно было сократить всё до одной строчки, но если хорошо поискать, можно найти эдак 10 причин, [почему не надо использовать onclick в HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

*PS: Обычные функции не принято называть с большой буквы. С большой буквы называют функции-конструкторы и классы.

Comment: text.value.split(" ").forEach(log); Я не понимаю до конца, как это работает. Split преобразует в массив, но получается, что массив состоит из одиночных элементов. Например, test1 -> t e s t 1. А forEach дальше перебирает массив. Для чего? И как в конце все это собирается, как нужно?

Comment: @ОлегЖафяров «test1 -> t e s t 1» (c) — split ведет себя так, только если написать `"test1".split("")` — выставив разделитель - пустую строку. А если в split передана `" "` пробельная строка, из `"test1 test2 test3".split(" ")` выходит массив `["test1", "test2", "test3"]`. Он как-бы удаляет переданную подстроку, а всё что осталось между - уйдут как элементы будущего массива. `console.log( "10203".split("0") ) // ["1", "2", "3"]`. А forEach нужен только для вывода элементов через console.log.

Comment: `function GetString(massiv) { massiv.split(" "); for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { toArray(massiv[i]);}}

function toArray(word) { alert(word) }`
Решил воспользоваться только split. И после хочу через alert посмотреть элементы после преобразования, но в итоге получаю тоже самое. Например, "test1 test2" -> t e s t 1 пробел t e s t 2

Comment: @ОлегЖафяров `massiv.split(" ")` — split вызывается, возвращает ожидаемый массив, но этот массив никуда не присваивается и пропадает из памяти) `massiv = massiv.split(" ");` ← нужно присвоить его в переменную → `for (let i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) { toArray(massiv[i]) }`

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за помощь